# How to switch keys in a Map to Association

Tags: list-manipulation, map, associations

I have an association that has parameters for a function. These parameters represent two cases that need to be applied to the function.  Some parameter values are common to both cases but some are unique to each case.

I need to execute the function for both cases of the parameters. I get the parameters for both cases in a single list per event. I've represented this below for a function `f[a,b,c]` where parameters `a` and `b` are common to both cases but for parameter `c` case 1 uses `c1` and case 2 uses `c2`.

```
assoc = AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c1", "c2"}, #] & /@ RandomInteger[20, {3, 4}];
```

So far I've managed to get the two list of the function calls but the parameter `c` in the function call is not evaluating to the value of the association; see below. I've not been able to figure out how to get the `Key` function to return the value of the key when it is mapped.

```
Transpose[(Function[{k}, f[#a, #b, Key[k]]] /@ {"c1", "c2"}) & /@ assoc]
(*
 {{f[13, 7, Key["c1"]], f[5, 11, Key["c1"]], f[6, 16, Key["c1"]]}, 
  {f[13, 7, Key["c2"]], f[5, 11, Key["c2"]], f[6, 16, Key["c2"]]}}
*)
```

How do I proceed? I've thought of using `MapIndexed` but it seems like a lot of mapping and remapping to get the result. I think there must be a *cleaner* way to get this. Yes?

Comment: Use `#[[Key[k]]]]`. Btw it's hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is your desired output? Your description is very hard to follow...

Comment: @StefanR I've updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `Key[k]` with `#[[Key[k]]]`.

Comment: With this I was able to realize that I can replace `Key[k]` with just `#[k]` since it is the association that is being mapped in.  For some reason I was thinking that each value was being mapped in. I think I've been looking at the screen for too long. :)

Comment: @Edmund Shall I close this as "simple mistake" in that case?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sure.